# facebook page with login not sending APP ID

Tags: facebook, joomla, facebook-login, app-id

I have a code that works in one web, and when I try it in another web it doesnt work. The code should build a login button but the button is not displayed because it seems that the app id is not sent. The code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<?php


defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup ({
                cache: false
                });

var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='http://fshf.org/images/loading.gif' alt='loading...' style='margin-left:261px; margin-top:40px' />";


</script>
<link href="modules/mod_facebook/tmpl/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#erresira").remove();
        $("#popup").remove();
    });

    $("body").prepend( "<div id='erresira'></div>" );
    var window_h = $(window).height()/2;
    var window_w = $(window).width()/2;

    $("#popup").css({top:window_h,left:window_w});

    $("#popup").animate({
            left: "-=230px",
            width: "+=460px",
            top: "-=127px",
            height: "+=254px"
            }, 0 );
});
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({
        appId      : '205862336256764', 
        channelUrl : 'http://livebast.infoalbania.org/modules/mod_facebook/tmpl/channel.html', 
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true, 
        xfbml      : true  
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          allowed();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          FB.login();
        } else {
          FB.login();
        }
    });
};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function allowed() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        var page_id = "184393808323569";
        var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var loadUrl = "http://livebast.infoalbania.org/modules/mod_facebook/tmpl/ajax.php";
        $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl+"?user_id=" + uid );
    });
}

</script>
<div id="result"></div>

<div id="popup">
  <div id="login"> <img src="<?=$params->get('image');?>" />
    <p><strong>
      <?=$params->get('content');?>
      </strong></p>
    <div id="appp">
      <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="230" max-rows="10"></fb:login-button>
    </div>
    <div id="like">
      <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/LiveBast" width="330" show_faces="false" send="false"></fb:like>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="close" class="close"></div>
</div>
```

the second page (the one where the code does not work is: livebast.infoalbania.org  and is on a PLESK server)

can this be an issue of a misconfiguration of the subdomain?

Comment: The above code is not to be found in the source of the page you mentioned.

Comment: http://livebast.infoalbania.org/video

Comment: Well, that gives a FB-related warning in the browser console, so please _look there_.